# How can I stop my straw rising?

Tags: food, drinks

When drinking a fizzy drink from a glass with a straw the straw often rises and sometimes falls out. What can I do to stop this?

I can hold the straw down with my hand, but some times I need to use it for e.g. Eating.

When I have the option, I can push the straw through a slice of lemon but lemons aren't always available and don't suit every drink

Comment: Hold your glass with one hand and straw with another.

Comment: Not a hack, but I'm a big fan of [metal straws](http://www.westelm.com/products/2756740/?catalogId=36&sku=2756740&bnrid=3918508&cm_ven=Google_PLA&cm_cat=Dining_+_Kitchen&cm_pla=Bar_Tools&cm_ite=West_Elm_Metal_Bendy_Straws_Set_-_Beige&srccode=cii_17588969&cpncode=26-373465542-2).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because drinking straws are *not* 100% smooth, they are perfect nucleation sites for bubbles to attach to. ([Source](http://realdoctorstu.com/2011/01/11/when-i-pour-a-fizzy-drink-why-do-bubbles-stick-to-the-straw/))

Here's what you can do:

- Take it out and lick it off
- Use ice cubes in your drink to prevent the straw from rising as quickly
- Use a bigger straw that can't be lifted by a few bubbles of CO<sub>2</sub>

Comment: "they are perfect nucleation sites for bubbles to attach to" ooh yeeeeees, that bubbly root beer…

Answer (score 20):

[image]

[Thread a Straw Through the Tab on a Soda Can to Keep It from Rising](http://lifehacker.com/5875457/thread-a-straw-through-the-tab-on-a-soda-can-to-keep-it-from-rising)

> It's as simple as turning the tab to the side and sliding the straw
>   through it. This keeps the straw from rising up and falling out of the
>   can.

Take some tape, wrap it around the straw and tape it to the jar. This will stop rising and the straw is in a fixed place.

Also, try getting heavier reusable straws;   this will make the straw stay down better, but may not work.

If the straw has ridges, take a string, wrap it around the straw and then tie it around the cup.

Getting a lid with a hole in it works too.

Comment: +1 for tab solution to the problem. Handy, simple, effective - check.

Answer (score 4):

As a short term solution, give the glass a quick swizzle with the straw, this will flatten the drink slightly which will help slow the rate of the straw rising as there will be less CO2 bubbles trying to carry the straw away.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a glass straw, like this:

> [image]
> [original image](http://img2.timeinc.net/instyle/images/2010/gallery/031610-Straw-400.jpg)

Or a metal straw:

> [image]
>
> [original image](http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server6000/20e6b/products/195/images/2345/straws__88645.1409663212.1280.1280.jpg)

Those straws are simply not light enough to be lifted by CO<sub>2</sub>

Also, personally I like the paper cups similar to Coca Cola ones with the cap that you can get at many fast food restaurants:

> [image]
>
> [original image](http://www.delisupplies.co.uk/images/detailed/3/coca-cola-lid.jpg)

Even if you don't want to use the glass anymore, bin it, but leave the cap and try to put it on the one of the glasses you like.

Comment: @Moo yep, edited to include a link to the source. Didn't notice that provided wrong link earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Rubber band, once around the straw, then looped around the rim

Comment: Welcome to the site, with a great tip. However, do please write more than one line solution if possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

to build on the elasctic band idea.

wrap the band round the straw then arround the glass, either top to bottom or round it. This would hold the straw and the glass and hold them together.