# How can I save space in my closet?

Tags: home, efficiency, storage, bedroom

The *coat* closet (no shelves, just a rod) near the front door is already full of jackets, coats and hoodies. Visitors hardly find a free space for their jackets or coats.

I can't increase the size of the rod, because there are two tall cupboards next to it. The whole entrance was built with the house, thus the coat closet and the cupboards are connected with the wall and cannot be exchanged easily.

> How can I make storing jackets on the rod more efficient and save space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soda can tabs can be used to accomplish various tasks. [That](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/1702/1238) is one of them.

Also this problem can be solved using soda can tabs. Thread a hanger through one hole of the soda can tab. Use the second hole in the soda can tab to hang another hanger. By now you realize that Red Bull can tabs don't work well because they have their bull-logo instead of a second hole.

[image: offset-hangers]

Depending on the stability of your initial hanger you can repeat this as many times as you want
[image: repeat]

Another method not dependent on the stability of the soda can tabs or the initial hanger uses **a chain** instead.

[image: offset-chain]

Comment: The chain method is great.